# Connecting to VMWare Workstation Server crashes the service

Tags: networking, crash, services, vmware-workstation

I am unsure whether this question belongs here, on Super User, or on Server Fault, so if it is in the wrong place I apologize.

I have two systems involved here: an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system and a Windows 10 Pro system.  What I am trying to do is share a virtual machine from the Ubuntu system to the Windows system, so that it is run over the network and the Ubuntu system, which has a much more powerful CPU, can handle the heavy lifting.  I set up VMWare Workstation Server, and put the VM in question in the shared VMs folder.  However, when I try to connect to the server, I get errors on both systems.

The Windows machine gets an error saying "Failed to connect to linux-system. A connection to the server could not be established."  The Ubuntu machine gets an error saying "The connection to the VMWare Workstation Server was unexpectedly lost."  Restarting the service allows me to get to the VM on the Ubuntu system, but I still can't reach it from the Windows system.

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking like the problem is that my version of VMWare isn't quite compatible with Ubuntu 20.04.